# Left column image vertically align

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a small left icon column, and right text field.

This is what I got on the left size ..
 [image]

What happens is that I have multiple text areas some big some small, and the left icon is not vertically aligned to the middle of each input field.

```
   <div class="form-container ">
                  <div class="leftColumn"> </div>
                  <textarea type="text" name="name" class="titleForm" placeholder="Type Your ..." ></textarea>
            </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.form-container{

    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    width: 90%;

}

.leftColumn{

    background-image:url("/images/tagIcon.png");
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 5%;
    height: 10%;


}


.titleForm {
    width: 90%;
    height: 10%;
    font-family: LucidaGrande-Bold;
    font-size:36px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(240,240,240,1.0);


}
```

**How would I make a small, left, vertically aligned icon , with right input field ?**

Comment: Can you create a sandbox version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding  `display: flex;  and align-items: center;` in your form container?

i.e something like this

```
.form-container{
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    width: 90%;

}
```

You can see the JSfiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/tc5wnvfx/

Note: In the fiddle I have added **test in between my div**  Test  but you can include icon and it should probably work

Comment: Thanks ! it actually worked ! can you explain why the flex matter  ? how putting it change the result ?

Comment: Also why changing the width of the leftColumn from 5% to 2% makes the icons go up again ?  in mobile this will not work, it will change position when I make the window smaller.

Comment: This article might help - https://medium.freecodecamp.org/an-animated-guide-to-flexbox-d280cf6afc35

Comment: It should work in mobile as well, I will check the same the behavior on mobile device once I reach home.